# How to stop decimal numbers from converting into dates in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a list of many decimal numbers that I want to copy-paste into excel.
When I paste them, excel thinks that I was inputing dates instead of decimal numbers, and automatically changes them, for example:

3.7 *is changed to:* 3.July

If I then try to format cells as text, the date is changed to something like 44380, but not to 3.7 which I am looking to get.

If I first format cells as text, I can write 3.7 and it will stay that way. But when I copy and paste my numbers, they once again appear as 3.July.

Can anyone help me solve my problem, and tell me if there is a way to disable the automatic conversion of numbers to dates?

Comment: Formatting the cells first, does this happen if you Paste Special -> Values only?

Comment: That's unusual.  What country and what are your Windows Regional Short Date settings?  What is your digit grouping symbol?  And Event code behind the worksheet?

Comment: The dates were displayed in Croatian with short date displayed as 12.5.2021. The problem is solved using the method mentioned by @DávidLaczkó

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld It also depends on where the data is being copied from. The metadata of the clipboard may misguide.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I still wonder though that does it only work with preformatted to text or also as number? The latter should be a solution, the former is rather a workaround.

Comment: Preformatted to number it outputs 44413,00 instead of 5.8 and so on, the same that it would output as if it was converted from date to number.

Comment: That's annoying...

Comment: But in Croatia, the decimal symbol is a `,` comma.  So shouldn't you be entering your data as `5,7`?  Or is the data coming from a CSV file?  If so, **IMPORTING** the file will allow you to properly apply the correct formats.